# WCF RIA Services, SL4

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-ria-services

After I edit an entity and save it, how do I reload the datasource to refresh the entities? I have a listbox with entities, and after I edit the entities the datasource is still showing the old information. the MyEntityDataSource.Load() method is not working.

The problem arises because I am not navigating to a separate page to do the editing. I am reusing the flipping window from the SLBA template. So when I flip back to the front, i'm basically still using the old object that are still in memory, not creating new objects that will fetch the data again. So I need to renew the old data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that the `ItemsSource` property of the `ListBox` is bound to a collection of objects that implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface .   Ideally the collection itself will implement the `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface (such as the `ObservableCollection` generic class).